# VSTO how add image from embedded resources

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, embedded-resource

I try import image to Word file from embedded resources. But i don't know how do it.

For example:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Resources1.ImageLogo.ToString());
```

But it isn't work, becose need full path to file as string.

> Globals.ThisDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\tmp\ImageLogo.jpg");

How can i import (add) image from embedded resources to Word file?
Thanks a lot!

I tried insert as "stream file", but my knowledge is not enough, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [InlineShapes.AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture) method doesn't accept streams or any other .net types. You need to save the embedded file to the disk and then specify the file path to the method. The first parameter is the path and file name of the picture.

Comment: Thank’s for your answer. Yes, I tried this. Good decision. Maybe are there other options?)

Comment: No, the Word object model is designed to deal with local files saved to the disk only.

Comment: I found another way (gimmick). Get image from clipboard.
For example:
Clipboard.SetImage(Resource1.ImageLogo);
Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection.Paste();

But there are one problem. I don't know how to get referens as «InlineShaper» object (or shapes) after "Paste()" method.

The first solution has a lack of permissions (potentially). And sorry for my english :)(